# Banning problematic users in a social iOS app without an identifying unique ID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uniqueidentifier, ios7

I have a social iOS app that has thousands of users (and most of them are children ages 10-13).  Occasionally someone shows up that wants to cause trouble, and I wind up banning them.

Previously I used a hashed MAC address to identify the user's device, but now in iOS 7 that MAC address will no longer be accessible.  Apple's solution is to use the advertising identifier.

The problem is that the advertising ID can be reset.  If a user causes problems, gets banned and then resets their ID, I wont be able to block them.  They'll essentially look like a new user.

Any solution to this?  Perhaps I need to rethink banning users altogether?  It pains me to think I wont be able to keep out the abusive users.

Comment: I found some great information on banning users in a social network here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html

Answer (score 2):

I think banning like this is not a good idea.
Because if the banned user sells his iPhone to someone, the new owner can't use your app.

So are you using any user Id for logging in ? If yes. Block them according to the UserId. Blocking them using the device Id is not a good solution (It's my suggestion)

Comment: Blocking users IDs will work most of the time, but a diligent troublemaker will simply create a new account and continue causing trouble.  Perhaps IPs associated with banned users wont allow new account creation (or login) for a certain time period.

Comment: @OneAndZeroes: That's true. But think about real world examples of some social media websites and communities. They usually ban the user by their userId not with the IP (There are some sites they ban using IP). If the trouble maker makes another account and makes problem, again they ban the new userId. If they ban using IP issue will occur with public computers (Internet Cafe). Like this you need to choose between this. If you choose to ban using unique Id, there is no way to do this (because the unique Identifier property is removed and newly added properties for identifiers can be reset)

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 7 onwards, you can't get any ID that identifies the phone itself - the advantage is that if someone who is suspended sells their phone, the buyer won't be suspended.

Check this answer: [IdentifierForVendor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528978/identifierforvendor)

identifierForVendor gives you a string that is unique to that installation of your app on that phone. So for privacy reasons, you still cannot identify the phone, but the installation of the app. That should be enough. You could also store the number in the keychain, so uninstalling and reinstalling the app wouldn't help.