# Can one get the identifierForVendor (IDFV) on iOS 7 given the bundle ID?

Tags: ios, ios7, uniqueidentifier

Let's say that on my device I have apps from two bundle IDs corresponding to two vendors:

com.example0
com.example1

Say I have two apps installed for each. How would I retrieve the IDFV for those vendors and display it? My understanding is that, for each vendor, the IFDV is the same for all of that vendor's apps as long as I don't uninstall every app from them (if I do then the IDFV will be reset). For example, com.example0's two apps both have the same IDFV unless I uninstall both apps and reinstall them.

Comment: The "IDFV" can change even on the same device. Delete all apps from the vendor then reinstall an app from the same vendor and a new "IDFV" will be generated. And the same app on two different devices will give two different "IDFV" values.

Comment: Thanks, I've made some edits to make my question a little clearer. I understood that the IDFV isn't set forever, but I was wondering how to retrieve the current IDFV given the vendor's bundle ID ("com.example0").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer on this thread. Apple has changed how IDFV was intended to work.
[identifierForVendor Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528978/identifierforvendor)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can get the IDFV from the vendor's bundle ID. I think you can only get the current IDFV for the vendor of the current app using:

```
NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```